# uicollectionview variable cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a reusable header (that's why I'm using collection and not tableview). The cell needs to have a variable height, depending on a UILabel. I know in UITableView you can use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to auto resize the cell, but I can't find an analogous function for UICollectionView. Any idea? I suppose I should start with sizeForItemAtIndexPath ?

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let height = // needs to be variable
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)


}
```

Comment: "I have a UICollectionView with a reusable header (that's why I'm using collection and not tableview)" I don't understand this.

Comment: Regardless, if you want to have dynamically sized cells, you're on the right path.

Comment: i stated the part about the reusable header, because if not for that, then my needs would be perfectly suited by a UITableView, whose cells I know how to make auto self-resize. i just put it there in case anyone wanted to recommend that I just use a tableview instead, to let them know I can't.

Comment: Peyman's point is uitableview has reusable headers.

Comment: Perhaps he meant "variable size headers"?

Answer (score 0):

Setup the cell with auto layout constraints then set the `estimatedItemSize` property of the your UICollectionView's UICollectionViewFlowLayout. For example:

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(100,100)
```